# Adding amount value to a form input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal, payment-gateway

I currently have a donation form that accepts variable amounts for payment. 
I've included Stripe as a payment method and now want to include PayPal.

To pass the donation amount to Stripe I use this method because the form is in JavaScript

```
var amount = document.querySelector('.total-box > span').innerText;
```

I also show the total amount to the user like this:

```
<span class="total-box"><span></span></span>
```

I need to know how to add the above `var amount` or `span class` to the Amount Value of this hidden input field on the PayPal button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend using the standard `.textContent` rather than the somewhat-weird IE `.innerText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation on the input element, `hidden.value`

```js
var amount = document.querySelector('.total-box > span').innerText;
var hidden = document.querySelector("input[name='amount']");

hidden.value = amount;
console.log("Value of hidden input:", hidden.value);
```

```html
<span class="total-box"><span>3</span></span>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
```

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you for the quick reply. The only issue I'm having is the value is not making it to PayPal. I believe it's needing to be able to be used in multiple places or be updatable. In my form the user can add the PayPal fees and in console log it only shows up once on page load, and doesn't update with the fees attached. Here is a JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/3x3bv3j6/49/